# jQuery: Delay hover until second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

In my application, I have a "following" button that I display to the user once they click another button "follow", exactly like Twitter does it.

My small issue is that when the user clicks follow and I display the "following" button, it immediately changes to "Unfollow" because that's the hover event I am attaching to it. Some code to illustrate:

```
$('.following').hover(
  function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.val("Unfollow");
  },
  function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.val("Following");
  }
);
```

This is because when the "following" button shows up, it ends up behind the cursor, therefore triggering the hover event. What I would like to achieve is **some way to delay this hover event until the mouse pointer exits the button for the first time then returns to it**. This is how Twitter does it and I think it's an excellent UI improvement.

Comment: Could you provide relevant HTML markup and CSS in question? A code snippet or jsFiddle would be helpful too

Comment: Clicking is not hovering.

Comment: Use css to decorate your button on hover and remove a css class on mouseout to handle the usecase when you just clicked on follow

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('.follow').click(function(){          
        if($(this).attr("class") == "follow"){
            $(this).one("mouseleave",function(){
                $(this).mouseover(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.html("Unfollow");
                }).mouseout(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.html("Following");
                });
            });
        }else{
            $(this).off('mouseover mouseout');
            $(this).html('follow');
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("follow following");
    });
```

example:[http://jsfiddle.net/z3t5r3ud/](http://jsfiddle.net/z3t5r3ud/1/)
Try this one.
I prefer to use css but maybe you have to use javascript for some reasons.

Comment: Just for fun, maid the example in css I was talking about : http://codepen.io/topheman/pen/vEKzZL maybe it could help someone one day.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate the UI of Twitter for following/unfollowing a user, I would recommend you allow your program to know the state of the current follow. You can do this by use of a variable, or a `data-` attribute on your button. For my example in JSFiddle, I used a variable just to make it quicker.

[>> Live Example: JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6rxejo8/)

```
var isFollowing = false;
$(".following").click(function(){
    if(isFollowing == false) {
        isFollowing = true;
        $(this).html("Following");
    }
    else if (isFollowing == true) {
        isFollowing = false;
        alert("unfollowing!");
        $(this).html("Follow");
    }
});

$(".following").hover(
    function() {
        if (isFollowing == true) {
            $(this).html("Unfollow");
        }
    },
    function() {
        if (isFollowing == true) {
            $(this).html("Following");
        }
    }
);
```

-mbp